# How to use //wand command in Minecraft Java Edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-mods

I have seen a few Minecraft videos using the `wand` command. I would like to know 
how to use it because I have been using `/fill` and it is a tedious process to fill a space.

Comment: That's not a command in Java Edition (or any standard edition).  I believe this is added by the World Edit mod.

Comment: Googling your question title gives the answer. You could have just used a different text field and gotten the answer faster. See also: [tour]

Comment: BTW who downvoted this question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`//wand` is a tool added by the [WorldEdit](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/worldedit) mod to aid in completing otherwise monotonous tasks quickly in Minecraft. You can also get it as a [server plugin](https://dev.bukkit.org/projects/worldedit). As for learning how to do specific things, take a look at [the docs](https://worldedit.enginehub.org/en/latest/).